# Strange storm cloud in Worms Reloaded

Tags: worms-reloaded

I did an online match and happened that my opponent used a strange storm cloud on one of my worms.

This cloud remained some turns on the head of my worm and then disappeared, but I didn't really understood what was its effect.

Can you explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Marked For Death is a new weapon
>   introduced in Worms Reloaded. It is
>   activated by placing the cursor over
>   the target worm, then using it. The
>   afflicted worm will be marked with a
>   storm cloud over their head and they
>   will take highly increased damage
>   until their death.

Source: http://worms.wikia.com/wiki/Marked_For_Death

**Edit**: All attacks do double damage for the rest of the game.

Comment: I am not sure I understood. Does it mean that if the Worms is damaged by a grenade, for example, the damage amount will be higher than usual? In which percentage?

Comment: the wiki you quote has Marked for Death lasting for a single instance of taking damage, not the rest of the game.